# What is the c-wiz tag?

Tags: html, browser, tags

When I go on Google Drive and inspect the web page, I see a lot of  tags. What are these? They seem to be used for my user specific content (what files I have). How does my browser know how to render it?

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/
Anyway, any tag is valid tag at least from CSS point of view. There are frameworks like RiotJS, that expand this by letting you build your own components, that will be added to the DOM as legacy elements.

Answer (score 14):

It was a Javascript framework Google had invented many years back called Wiz. It's not open source. That's where you see those tags come in.